# DC analysis of Darlington pair

Tags: darlington

So I'm having this darlington pair here

[image: Darlington pair]

I'm doing DC analysis of this darlington pair

Can anyone explain why is R2 is 6.58, shouldn't it be aprx 7.39?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what Q4 actually is or represents.

Comment: My bad, I just changed it to R2 instead of Q4

Comment: 6.58 is approximately 7.39 when it comes to basic DC analysis of transistors. Anyway, R2 = 18 ohms according to your circuit and not 6.58 or 7.39.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned it correctly, I'm trying to ask about the DC voltage at the Emitter which is shown on R2(1) as 6.58V

Comment: Can you justify why you believe it should be closer to 7.39 volts. It should definitely be much closer to 6.58 volts than 7.39 volts so the answer boils down to understanding why you came up with 7.39 volts.

Comment: I think Vbe of Q1 is equal to Vbe of Q2 which is 0.7 volts, so the voltage drops about 0.7 volts through each transistor, like Q1(E) equals to 8.8 - 0.7 = 8.1 as shown. Sorry if my English is bad, hope you can understand what I'm saying

Comment: @MaiTho Why would the \$V_\text{BE}\$ of both BJTs be the same? Their collector currents are nowhere near the same. So this doesn't make sense. They are most certainly different. And because the collector currents will be different by something on the same order as \$\beta\$, I'd expect the \$V_\text{BE}\$ differences to be on the order of \$26\:\text{mV}\cdot\operatorname{ln}\beta\$ for just the collector current ratio alone. Then there's \$r_b^{'}\$ and \$r_e^{'}\$ of \$Q_2\$ to account for, which probably doubles the result. Should be \$200-250\:\text{mV}\$ difference between them.

Comment: @MaiTho Their \$\beta\$ values will also be substantially different, as \$\beta\$ varies a fair amount with collector current. Your simulator is, though, probably way off. I don't know why. But the same circuit in LTspice provides quite a different result -- and one that is far closer to your own result. (I compute a somewhat lower value because I don't assume the base-emitter voltages are the same. But that's not a major mistake. I think you did well enough.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think Vbe of Q1 is equal to Vbe of Q2 which is 0.7 volts, so the
>   voltage drops about 0.7 volts through each transistor, like Q1(E)
>   equals to 8.8 - 0.7 = 8.1 as shown.

No, it's not as simple as that. If you look at the [data sheet for the 2N2222](https://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/2n2222-datasheet.pdf) you will see that the base emitter voltage might be as high as 1.3 volts for a collector current of 150 mA.

But it's all a bit hit and miss with the 2N2222 transistor because there are no graphs in the data sheet that could give typical values that are representative of actual circuit conditions. What can be said is that assuming a forward voltage of 0.7 volts for either transistor's Vbe is overly simplistic. It will be greater and quite possibly nearer to 1 volt for each transistor.

Also, worth pointing out is that the simulation tool that predicted 6.59 volts is subject to some speculation. The model it uses will have inaccuracies and these might slightly compound the "true" analysis.

Comment: +1. Comment only: Vbe is not going to need to be anything near saturated. Beta should be around 100 and certainly [tm] over 50. At Ic of about 400 mA , Ib of say 8 6 mA abs max needed and probably <= 3 mA.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon you are quite correct. I'm going to amend.